# Postgres SQL How to Pivot table on SQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, pivot, postgresql-9.3

Please help how to create sql query from this:

[image: raw data]

[image: expected output I want to get]

Like Pivot function in excel

Thank you

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional aggregation. The logic is:

```
select
    date,
    docnumber,
    source,
    doctype,
    notes,
    sum(total) where(account = 'Creditors') creditors,
    sum(total) where(account = 'GST') gst,
    sum(total) where(account = 'Expenses') expenses
from mytable 
group by
    date,
    docnumber,
    source,
    doctype,
    notes
```